# App crashes if while loading tweets i move to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, twitter

In my app i have integrated fetching tweets from twitter..when i move to twitter fragment page and then suddenly moves to another fragment while the twitter fragment is still loading tweets then my app crashes and displays following errors..

```
08-30 15:17:10.273   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The errors are showed in the line-

java:45

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

java:135

```
TwitterAdapter adapter = new TwitterAdapter(getActivity(), data, link, image, time, name, officialname);
```

java:77

```
private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

If on twitter fragment page i allow it to loads tweets which take arnd 4 seconds and then move to another fragment then app doesn't crashes..it only crashes if while loading tweets i move to another fragment..I don't know how to avoid such crash...

Comment: It is because getActivity() is return null.

Comment: @hoomi what should i change to avoid tht?nd how it returns null only if while loading tweets i move to another fragment?

Comment: You could just check if activity is null or not using an if statement in `onPostExecute`. This may fix your problem for now but I think you should consider why you are trying to show the results even if your fragment is not there anymore

Comment: @hoomi .. thanks for ur idea..putting TwitterAdapter adapter = new TwitterAdapter(getActivity(), data, link, image, time, name, officialname); inside try-catch block resoled the issue..u can submit this as an answer as u gave me the idea where null pointer exception is coming.

Comment: Thanks @user3753273 That gets rid of your NullPointerException but it does not solve your problem. Catching all exception is not always a good thing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `getActivity()` is returning null.

You could just check if activity is null or not, using an if statement in onPostExecute. This may fix your problem for now but I think you should consider why you are trying to show the results even if your fragment is not there anymore

Comment: putting TwitterAdapter adapter = new TwitterAdapter(getActivity(), data, link, image, time, name, officialname); inside try-catch block resoled the issue..My activity has many fragments nd i was facing this problem if while loading tweets in twitter fragment i move to some another fragment while the loading of tweets still not being completed..